# Is it possible to enable ediff features by default?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I often use ediff-directories to diff directories containing many c/c++ files. Whenever I enter a file I always '##' to ignore white space in the diff.

This becomes a problem when I have many files to diff. Is there any way to ignore white space automatically?

Comment: I was able to add (setq ediff-diff-options "-w") to my init.el. This variable defines the options that are passed to the diff program that is run under the hood. -w tells diff to ignore white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(setq-default ediff-ignore-similar-regions t)
```

You may need

```
(setq-default ediff-auto-refine 'on)
```

as well.

Comment: This worked along with the other method I found. Thank you!